# JLabel Overlapping

Tags: java, swing, layout, jlabel, overlap

I have created  a label with overriding its `paintComponent` (to paint it in a different format with an arc) and located them on a panel. Everything worked fine, however the labels which are located in same location (by `.setlocation`) are creating problems.

Lets say I have 3 labels at the same location with different shapes. A-B-C
A is first created, then B is created and lastly c is created.
When I click on A, my function paints A and displays "youve clicked A"

But when I click on B or C, it acts like i have clicked on A.

(I'm adding labels in a panel stacked in scroll pane )

Here is the code where i make labels

```
for(int i=0;i<rowcount;i++){
        arcstart = Rawazimuth(azimuth[i]);
                    //custom JLabel to paint it like an arc
        MyLabel FLabel = new MyLabel(100, 50, (int)arcstart,cellid[i],lon[i],lat[i]);
        FLabel.setOpaque(true);
        Dimension LabelSize = new Dimension( 100,50);
        FLabel.setSize(LabelSize);
                    //locate the JLabel to labels location. it might be same or not
        FLabel.setLocation(lon[i], lat[i]);

        MyPanel.add(FLabel);    
}
```

this is my custom jlabel class

```
public MyLabel(int W, int H, int start,int outcellid,int lonn, int latt) {
    addMouseListener(this);
    arcsizeW = W;
    arcsizeH = H;
    arcstart = start;
    cellid = outcellid;
    clicked = false;
    lon = lonn;
    lat = latt;
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    // true if button is clicked, so paint acordingly
    if(clicked ==true){
       g.setColor(dummyg.getColor());  
   }else{
       g.setColor(Color.blue);
   }
  // draw the arc
   g.fillArc(0, 0,arcsizeW , arcsizeH, arcstart, 60);
}

 //if cell is clicked, change its color to red and print its cellid
@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

    System.out.println(cellid);

     dummyg = this.getGraphics();
     dummyg.setColor(Color.red);
    this.paintComponent(dummyg);
    clicked = true;
}// other listener stuff}
```

so how do i prevent this?
i think i can use jlayerpane, but i will need at least 4 layers ( dunno if its ok ).

Comment: Please learn java naming conventions and stick to them.

Comment: can please tell us what layout are you using in your JPanel, default is FlowLayout, and it now allow to overlap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem.

The real problem that i found was, Java is interpreting each component with their x,y location and width & height. So even if your label does not overlap ( graphically ) they can be interpreted as same component.

To solve my problem,
I found the angle between mouse click point and component center; then calculated the closest component and reached it.

Layers and such doesn't work in this situation, the only other way around is possibly overriding the contains method for the actualy shape.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you are calling `super.paintComponent`.  This is important to ensure that the component is painting correcting.

Mouse events are like rain.  They will hit the first component registered to receive mouse events and stop (like rain hitting an umbrella).

If you have components that overlap, where they overlap, the mouse events go to the first component registered to handle them (in this case A).

Here's a quick example to show what I mean...

[image]
[image]

As you hover over each circle, it will highlight, try hovering over the middle...

```
public class OverlappingMouseTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new OverlappingMouseTest();
    }

    public OverlappingMouseTest() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new BackgroundPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }            
        });
    }

    protected class BackgroundPane extends JLayeredPane {

        private CirclePane redPane;
        private CirclePane greenPane;
        private CirclePane bluePane;

        public BackgroundPane() {            
            redPane = new CirclePane(Color.RED);
            greenPane = new CirclePane(Color.GREEN);
            bluePane = new CirclePane(Color.BLUE);

            add(redPane);
            add(greenPane);
            add(bluePane);            
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        public void doLayout() {            
            Dimension size = new Dimension(100, 100);
            int width = getWidth() - 1;
            int height = getHeight() - 1;

            Point p = new Point();
            p.x = (width / 2) - 50;
            p.y = (height / 2) - 75;            
            redPane.setBounds(new Rectangle(p, size));

            p.x = (width / 2) - 75;
            p.y = (height / 2) - 25;
            bluePane.setBounds(new Rectangle(p, size));

            p.x = (width / 2) - 25;
            p.y = (height / 2) - 25;
            greenPane.setBounds(new Rectangle(p, size));            
        }        
    }

    protected class CirclePane extends JPanel {

        private boolean mouseHover = false;

        public CirclePane(Color background) {
            setOpaque(false);
            setBackground(background);
            addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseExited(MouseEvent me) {
                    mouseHover = false;
                    repaint();
                }

                @Override
                public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent me) {
                    mouseHover = true;
                    repaint();
                }                
            });
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(100, 100);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics grphcs) {            
            super.paintComponent(grphcs);

            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) grphcs.create();
            if (!mouseHover) {
                g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, 0.5f));
            }
            g2d.setColor(getBackground());
            g2d.fill(new Ellipse2D.Float(0, 0, getWidth() - 1, getHeight() - 1));
            g2d.dispose();            
        }        
    }    
}
```

Comment: @kleopatra gotta keep you guys happy ;)

Comment: @Robin Picture speaks a thousands words. Also, my time and hands are taken up with a 6 month old, I very grateful for code macros :P

Comment: i've used jlayeredpane, it really does set my components with different layers and as you have said, mouse events hit the first component ( tried it with changing layer order ). So, how can i bypass it? ( imagine those circles were in different size but located at the same exact point )

Comment: By default, you can't, the only way I can think is to capture the event on something like a glass pane and pass the mouse event to each component

Answer (score 3):

> Everything worked fine, however the JLabel's which are located in same
>   location ( by .setlocation ) are creating problems.
>
> Lets say i have 3 Jlabels at the same location with different shapes.
>   A-B-C A is first created, then B is created and lastly c is created.

there are tree ways, to use

- [JLayer (Java7), based on JXLayer (Java6)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/jlayer.html)
- [OverlayLayout](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/1401__OverlayLayout.htm)
- [JLayeredPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html)